# Operator overloading code compilation error, template argument deduction/substitution failure

Tags: c++, gcc, operator-overloading, argument-passing

I'm trying to apply some concepts of operator loading that I've learnt in the following  C++ class.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point
{
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Point(int, int);
    Point operator+(const Point&);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Point&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Point&);
    Point operator=(const Point&);
};

Point::Point(int x = 0, int y = 0)
    :x(x), y(y){}

Point Point::operator+(const Point& p)
{
    int r1, r2;
    r1 = x + p.x;
    r2 = y + p.y;
    return Point(r1, r2);
}

Point Point::operator=(const Point& p)
{
    this->x = p.x;
    this->y = p.y;
    return *this;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& in, Point& p)
{
    char openParenthesis, closeParenthesis, comma;
    cout << "Enter data in the format (1,2): ";
    in >> openParenthesis >> p.x >> comma >> p.y >> closeParenthesis;
    return in;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Point& p)
{
    out << "(" << p.x << "," << p.y << ")";
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    Point a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;

    cout << "a + b is: " << a + b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and runs fine on Visual Studio. But when I try to compile it on Linux with gcc, it throws a long list of errors along the lines of:

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39:0,
>                    from optr_overload.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:471:5: note: template std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, _CharT)
>        operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, _CharT __c)
>        ^ /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:471:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed: optr_overload.cpp:53:30: note:
>   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘_CharT’ (‘char’ and ‘Point’) 
>   cout << "a + b is: " << a + b << endl;

I understand that the problem lies with the line where I passed "a + b" to the overloaded binary stream insertion operator which only receives reference to one Point object as the argument. But I've no idea how to fix the code other than assigning "a + b" to a third object and pass that single object as the argument to "<<". Could someone explain to me what exactly needs to be done in order for gcc to compile my code, preferably without involving the use of an extra placeholder object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value computed with `a + b` is a temporary object and therefore cannot be passed as a `Point&` to `operator<<`; the language only allows temporaries to be passed as `const Point&` instead. Just change he declaration of the output operator to accept a `const Point&`.

Allowing passing a temporary result as a non-const reference was a known bug in old versions of VC++.

Comment: Your second point is not true. `operator<<` is defined as `friend` and can access `private` members.

Comment: @user0815: true. I fixed the operator definition without fixing the friend declaration (I didn't notice it was there) when testing. Fixed.

Comment: `const Point&`, or `Point&&`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: or `Point` or `const Point`. Kidding apart I'm desperately trying to resist using and talking about move semantics (IMO a bad addition to C++). Unfortunately we're doomed to face a plethora of new sources of undefined behavior once `x&&` will gain popularity (and misuse, and abuse) in C++ code.

Comment: That indeed fixes the issue. Thanks to everyone for the help! The funny thing is that I'm already using the latest version of Visual Studio and the problem appears to suggest that this bug in Microsoft's C++ compiler is still there. I generally try to compile my C/C++ programs on both platforms just to make sure I'm writing absolutely watertight code. So I guess it is a good practice to always declare the argument of the binary extraction operator as `const&` to avoid errors such as the one I encountered?

Comment: @bastille77: That's strange because apparently MS decided to fix this with VC++2005 (emitting warning C4350). Are you compiling with warnings enabled? ... that should ALWAYS be done when working with C++. Anyway yes, stream output operators are expected to accept const references.

Comment: @6502 I'm not sure about the plethora of new undefined behaviours. In that sense it is pretty much the same as C++03.

Answer (score 1):

You've got almost everything right, but your `ostream& operator<<()` should take Point by a const reference:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Point&);
```

This should fix your issue.

(And don't worry about `Point::x` and `Point::y` being private, you've already declared your `operator<<` as a friend.)